# MyBB Portal Homepage .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain, forum, mybb

I was needing to make the portal.php my homepage for my MyBB forum, but I'm not exactly sure how to do this.

Gonna use example URLs here.

I need subdomain.example.com to open subdomain.example.com/portal.php instead of subdomain.example.com/index.php, without affecting the pages under the main domain, example.com

Answer (score 0):

The change switch between [MyBB Portal](http://hardforo.com/thread-127.html) and your index you just need to use DirectoryIndex in this way:

```
DirectoryIndex portal.php index.php
```

You just put in the right order in the .htaccess where you need it.